# Helm ignores specified version and installs latest

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

Me and my colleague have an issue, whenever I type

```sh
helm install mystuff-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --version 3.26.0
```

I have successfully deployed nginx in version `3.26.0`, however when he runs the same command on his laptop just with different name `mystuff-nginx-1` he installs it in the lastest version `4.0.1`, and idea what's going on ? We have helm, gcloud and kubectl in the same versions, even redownloaded the binary.

and we know the version is available

```sh
MacBook-Pro-2% helm search repo -l ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx                     4.0.2           1.0.1       Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx                     4.0.1           1.0.0       Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx                     3.37.0          0.49.1      Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx                     3.36.0          0.49.0      Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx                     3.35.0          0.48.1      Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
...
ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx                     3.26.0          0.44.0      Ingress controller for Kubernetes using NGINX a...
```

Comment: note: now he connected via ssh from his windows machine, and it installs correctly, he does the command from mac 20sec later and its latest all the time again &_&

Comment: i believe this is the mac/terminal used intercepting the --version param. Can you try  `helm install mystuff-nginx --version 3.26.0 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx`  and see if it leads to anywhere?

Comment: we tried it now, not helping

Comment: To confirm the guess above, please try to add `--debug` option to see if any flags are passed to `helm`. Also what version of helm is used? How it was installed on mac?

Comment: he uninstalled kubectl and helm, then installed and the command worked - we have no idea what was wrong back then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Helm's documentation:

```
helm install [NAME] [CHART] [flags]
```

The version flag:

```
--version string               specify a version constraint for the chart version to use. This constraint can be a specific tag (e.g. 1.1.1) or it may reference a valid range (e.g. ^2.0.0). If this is not specified, the latest version is used
```

So, you can try:

```
$ helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --version "3.26.0"
```

helm list:

```
NAME            NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                   APP VERSION
nginx-ingress   default     1           2021-09-24 09:44:54.261772858 -0300 -03 deployed    ingress-nginx-3.26.0    0.44.0
```

I used the helm version v3.5.4 and a k3d cluster to test.

Comment: Did you run `helm` on mac? How did you install it? It does work on `linux` without any questions.

Comment: Hey @moonkotte:  Yes. I used a friend's mac to test helm (it runs a Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0). I updated the helm version to `3.7.0` and it worked as well. I installed using brew.